# Is PVC conduit OK above ground to hook up a Jacuzzi?

Tags: electrical, pvc, conduit, hot-tub

We are hooking up a Jacuzzi and need to run # 8 wire above ground What PVC should we use to run under our house to get to the back yard? I have read Schedule 80 PVC will work.

Comment: I have to strongly say, you had better know what you are doing and know ALL the applicable codes involved with wiring a spa or hot tub, and there are many. This is NO PLACE to mess around if you are feeling your way through.

Comment: Why only #8? Many/most full-sized spas require #6cu. Is the spa 240V, or 120/240V? Do you know what equipotential bonding is?

Comment: If it is a listed self-contained spa, equipotential bonding is no longer required. 680.42(B) 2014 NEC. You should use the breaker size and wire size recommended by the manufacturer.

Comment: Thanks, yes we are and the spa is 240V.  I just want the wire in a PVC tube that is being ran under the house from our GFI box to the quick disconnect to the spa and I was told that I can't use PVC because it gets to hot. I will check on the #6cu. We where using the same wire that it was hook-up to when we pulled it from another location.

Answer (score 1):

Schedule 80 will be required if exposed (above ground). Annex C of the NEC shows #8 THHN,THWN,THWN2; 3 wires in 1/2" and 5 wires in 3/4". You should be feeding the tub with a GFCI breaker.

Comment: This brings back the debate of what does "exposed to physical damage" mean. The Code does not define it. There are millions of homes in this country with schedule 40 PVC or SE cable being used for their service. Neither of these are identified for exposure to physical damage. Schedule 80 PVC can be used in all areas so I would agree its use is advisable but it is not necessarily required. It may be a good idea to ask the local inspector.

Comment: Thanks, Yes we are running if from the GFI breaker to the quick disconnect to the spa, I wanted the 4 wire to be in something from the box to the quick disconnect. This will be under our home. We are getting so many different answers on this from our area, that is why I'm asking here to got more advise. I will check on schedule 40 PVC. Thanks

Comment: Under the house schedule 40 is fine but once it exits the foundation it is exposed to damage schedule 40 will not meet code schedule 80 will.